# Script to copy log files from linux server to windows shared server

Tags: windows, bash, shell, unix, shared

Need to create a shell script to copy all the logs everyday from Linux server to Windows Shared server.

sudo mount //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2TB /home/pi/mntPassport -o username=root,password=********,vers=1.0

sudo mount //192.168.1.250/PASSPORT2TB /home/pi/mntPassport -o username=root,password=********,vers=1.0

mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this way, on my network:

```
smbclient //192.168.77.199/sharedFolder -U user --pass password -D "folder" -c "put $FILE1"
```

where //192.168.77.199 is my windows machine.

but, before, you can test if your share is ok, with:

```
smbclient  -L \\192.168.77.199 -U user
```

Comment: Thank you, It says this

Comment: smbclient -L \\172.19.116.93 -U oracle
Unknown parameter encountered: "client min protocol"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client min protocol"
Unknown parameter encountered: "client max protocol"
Ignoring unknown parameter "client max protocol"
Enter oracle's password:
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: Do we have any other way we can copy the files from Linux Server to Windows Shared server.

Answer (score 0):

Install SAMBA on the Linux box, share the logs folder (read only would suffice), and copy them from the Windows side.

EDIT: to share the folder, edit `smb.conf`, which is usually under `/etc/samba/`. Add a section:

```
[logs]
path = /foobar/whatever
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
```

This will create a share called `logs` on the Linux machine, and it will correspond to whatever directory you provide under `path`.

Then copy the files from the Windows side, using Windows' regular `copy` or `xcopy` commands, using `\\linuxmachine\logs` as the source. What else are you having a problem with?

In this scenario, the Linux machine is the file server and the Windows machine is the client, not vice versa like in the question.

Comment: Seva, Can you please share the steps. I installed Samba on Linux.

Comment: Seva,Then copy the files from the Windows side, using Windows' regular copy or xcopy commands, using \\linuxmachine\logs as the source. My requirement is to just copy the files from Linux Box to Windows Shared Server.

Comment: Do you need to copy the files as an interactive user, or on a schedule?

Comment: Using Linux service account i need to copy the files to Shared Server

Comment: Can you log on to the Windows machine with Remote Desktop?